# .NET HTTP POST Method - Cookies AirFrames.org

Tags: c#, post, cookies, httpwebrequest

Trying to use C# to POST HttpWebRequest into airframes.org for aircraft information. This is the code I use for many other POST request with no problems (used with other urls), but it / I am not able to load the airframes.org page using ICAO24 number (A64294).

```
        var cookies = new CookieContainer();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.airframes.org/");
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            writer.Write("reg=&selcal=&icao24=A64294&submit=submit");
        }

        using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
```

Comment: What error/response are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the site has a [no-bots policy](http://www.airframes.org/nobots.php), which is why your request won't work.

That being said, if you still wish to request the page, adding a user-agent string (so your request looks like it came from a browser) does the trick:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1";
```

It is usually a good idea to respect the policies of a site. The code above is merely for educational purposes.

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly. I did not notice the site request for no-bots. I will contact the site for permission.